# Represent SQL Server table data in Power BI dektop table but with one extra column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, powerbi-desktop

I have a table in SQL Server that contains document-related data. Data entry in this table is handled from ASP.NET code:

[image: This table has Document related data. Data entry in this table is handled within the asp.net code]

I have to show this table data in PowerBI desktop. With normal Select query I could bind the data in table of Power BI desktop. But along with this table data I have to show one more column `IsProcessedBefore` which I have to compute for each row.

This column values could be '1' or '0':

- 1 indicates that this particular Document Number has been processed earlier
- 0 indicates that this particular Document Number has not been processed earlier.

Output should be shown in Power BI desktop report as shown below.

[image]

I am not getting how could I compute this indicator for already existing data.

Whenever a new entry is done in the SQL Server table. It must be reflected same in the PowerBI report along with the computed indicator value.

Please help me with this scenario.

One way that I found is to create another page in same Power BI report, showing the number of times the documents processed using group by query on documentnumber and documentId (Output Shown below). But this is just workaround. Using this approach we will be having two pages. One could check documentnumber from actual table data in below output and refer its count. If its count is greater than 1 that means it is processed earlier.

[image].

But this workaround does not match up with the exact requirement.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can't you just add a calculated column to the query? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column